# Removing elements for non-admin users

Tags: custom-templates, jquery

There are several instances where I want to remove some buttons, inputs, tabs, etc on various screens for non-admin users. For instance, on the Event Search screen in this template

`CRM/Event/Form/Search.extra.tpl` I have

```
<script>
{literal}
//remove smart group creation
CRM.$(function remove_smart_group_creation($) {
 $('#task option[value=12]').remove();
});

//remove group add contacts
CRM.$(function remove_group_add_contacts($) {
 $('#task option[value=2]').remove();
});

//remove delete participants
CRM.$(function remove_delete_participants($) {
 $('#task option[value=4]').remove();
});
</script>
{/literal}
```

How could I exempt the administrator role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are they in the administrators group? Since then you might be able to do something like (untested):

```
CRM.api3('GroupContact', 'get', {
  "contact_id": "user_contact_id", // use this exact string to mean current user
  "group_id": "Administrators"
}).then(function(result) {
  if (result.count == 0) {
    // Not in the admin group
    // ** do your removal stuff here **
  }
});
```

There is also CRM.checkPerm() to check a CMS permission. See e.g. https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.18.4/templates/CRM/Tag/Page/Tag.tpl#L123, e.g. `CRM.checkPerm('administer reserved tags')`

```
if (!CRM.checkPerm("administer CiviCRM")) {
  // do your removal stuff
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the administrators group. It says 0 records are in it. But I tested with both admin and non-admin roles and it did not apply my jQuery.

Comment: Oh ok. Do you mean administrator role in the CMS (e.g. Drupal)? Or a civi ACL maybe?

Comment: I mean the administrator role in WP, not using ACL's. Using that group method would be fine but I worry that users could somehow add to that group? Seems like an obvious loophole. That group is only for ACL usage I assume. Alternatively, I have 4 non-admin user civi groups that all non-admins get put into I could apply the code to.

Comment: I updated answer to include CRM.checkPerm(), to check a CMS permission.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to put that all together...

Comment: Go to Administer - users and permissions - permissions. On that page near the middle there's a link to "wordpress access control". That page has a list of permissions. If you use one of those permission strings inside CRM.checkPerm() to tell if they have that permission or not, it returns true or false for the logged in user. Looking at the wordpress demo, the "CiviCRM Administrator" role has "administer CiviCRM" permission, which seems as good as any to use as the string to put in CRM.checkPerm("administer CiviCRM").

Comment: For some unknown reason, if I try to use a different permission than "administer CiviCRM", the check does not work.

Comment: It's case-sensitive is all I can think at the moment. Maybe also as listed on that permissions screen it has a prefix that you don't include, i.e. don't include the `CiviCRM:` or `CiviEvent:` part at the beginning.

Comment: It's not that issue. I have the perm entered properly. I am using .extra.tpl files. Frustrating as if I want to customize screen per user role other than non-admin I am out of luck.