# Only !CRM.checkPerm("administer CiviCRM")) conditional works

Tags: permissions, templates

If I put this (or any JQuery) in an .extra tpl file it works

```
{literal}
<script>
if (!CRM.checkPerm("administer CiviCRM")) {
CRM.$( function( $ ) {
    $( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, request, settings ) {
   //do stuff
 })
 })
 }
{/literal}
</script>
```

If I switch the permission away from **administer CiviCRM**, it does not work and executes the code for all users. Carrying over from here: [Removing elements for non-admin users](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/33464/removing-elements-for-non-admin-users#comment38397_33465).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use CRM.checkPerm() JS function than you will need to add permission using hook and than it will be catched in CRM.checkPerm() js function. eg: In hook

```
function extname_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
  if ('Some_FormName' == $formName) {
    CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->addPermissions('administer CiviCRM');
  }
}
```

and than in tpl

```
{literal}
<script>
  CRM.$( function( $ ) {
    if (!CRM.checkPerm("administer CiviCRM")) {
      $( document ).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
       //do stuff
      });
    }
  });
{/literal}
</script>
```

An other alternate could be

```
{if !call_user_func(array('CRM_Core_Permission','check'), 'administer CiviCRM')}
  {literal}
  <script>
    CRM.$( function( $ ) {
      $( document ).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
        //do stuff
      })
    });
  {/literal}
  </script>
{/if}
```

Comment: Wonderful. I tested a couple core permissions and it works. FWIW, I also tried keying off a permissioning created by your custom permissions ext but that apparently isn't included in the core permission check.

Comment: Have updated my answer how you can use CRM.checkPerm() functions

Comment: The custom permission extension does work, depends upon how you using it. You need to check against the value of the options rather label. If you can add some example than it would be good.

Comment: Can you mark this as answered if it has fixed the problem?

Comment: So if a custom permission has a option value of 1, what does that change?

Comment: You shouldn't have numeric as value, for reference see https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/custompermissions/-/blob/master/images/CustomPermission.gif

Comment: In your gif it shows value of 1

Comment: Ohh yeah sorry, it should be the name i.e civicrm_option_value.name field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105919/discussion-between-andy-burns-and-pradeep-nayak).